# Graph theory: Node as a set of entities

Tags: graph-theory

I am struggling with the question: Is it possible to have a graph in which a single node represents a group of similar objects? For example, if we have two sets **X** and **Y** of multiple objects, and a relation **R** between **X** and **Y**, can **X** and **Y** be represented as two nodes of a graph with **R** being the edge joining them?

Thanks for your help !

Cheers

Comment: You can certainly draw that graph and say it represents your situation. Whether that is a _useful_ thing to do depends on what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks for your reply. I found that this idea is similar to granularity in graphs.